# How to speed up a data file import in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

*Update as of June 11, 2019: I still haven’t figured out why practically all of my delay happens in those two lines, but current status is that I put up with the delay. So far, I have about 6000 rows of data in the master document, and an import process takes about 20 seconds regardless of how many rows I import.*

—

I have a "master document" and I import data from lots and lots of little documents all day long. I admit I'm not a super-genius here, and a lot of my coding habits come from doing it "old school" so there may be "Excel ways" that I don't know (but want to learn!).

The issue I'm seeing is how much time a data file import can take.

When I started the tool out, data imports took only a few seconds.

Now that I have about 3500 rows of data, data imports take about 15-20 seconds. It doesn't matter if I am importing one row or a hundred rows. I expect this to keep going up. By the time I get to 7000 rows or 10,000 rows, I expect it to become unbearable.

By using message boxes (remember: "old school"), I've been able to narrow the speed bottleneck down to two lines of code. Between "Step 1" and "Step 2" is about 30% of my delay, and between "Step 2" and "Step 3" is about 70% of my delay.

I've included the whole sub below to make sure I'm not missing something obvious, but I made sure to UNINDENT my message boxes so you can go r-i-g-h-t to the code I suspect. Also, I included the entire sub because usually one of the first responses is “can you show the whole sub so I have better context?”

Thank you kindly for any thoughts or suggestions you might have. :)

```
Private Sub Btn_ImportDataFiles_Click()
  ' Search the current worksheet and assign the next TransactionID
    Dim TransactionCounter As Integer
    Dim TransactionID As Long ' This is the next available Transaction ID
    TransactionID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("a:a")) + 1
  ' open the file and import the data
    Dim customerBook As Workbook
    Dim filter As String
    Dim caption As String
    Dim customerFilename As String
    Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

    ' make weak assumption that active workbook is the target
      Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    ' get the customer workbook
      filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
      caption = "Please Select an input file "
      customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

    If customerFilename <> "False" Then
    ' If they have uploaded the file before, let them know.
    ' If they want to keep uploading it, no harm done,
    ' but no need to stupidly add data that is already present.
    ' Select the archive sheet
      Sheets("Upload_Archive").Select
      Dim FileNameHunt As String
      Dim cell As Range
      Dim ContinueUpload As Boolean
      ContinueUpload = True
      FileNameHunt = Mid(customerFilename, InStrRev(customerFilename, "\") + 1)
      Columns("A:A").Select
      Set cell = Selection.Find(what:=FileNameHunt, after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
      If cell Is Nothing Then ' Add the new filename to the archive
        Sheets("Upload_Archive").Select
        Rows(1).Insert shift:=xlDown
        Range("a1:a1").Value = FileNameHunt
        Sheets("MasterSheet").Select
        Application.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
        Application.Cells.Font.Size = "8"
        Application.Cells.Font.Bold = False
      Else
        response = MsgBox("This data file has previously been uploaded. " & vbCrLf & "Do you want to cancel this upload?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Pressing [yes] will cancel the process." & vbCrLf & "Pressing [no] will continue with the file upload" & vbCrLf & "and add the data to the tracking sheet.", vbYesNo)
        If response = vbYes Then
          ContinueUpload = False
          Sheets("MasterSheet").Select
          Exit Sub
        End If
      End If ' If cell Is Nothing Then...

      If ContinueUpload = True Then
        ' Continue with data upload procedure
          Sheets("MasterSheet").Select
          Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
        ' Copy data from customer to target workbook
          Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
          Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
          Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
          Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
          Dim ImportRecordCount As Integer
          ImportRecordCount = sourceSheet.Range("B1")
          Dim ReconciliationID As String
          ReconciliationID = ""
          If sourceSheet.Range("E3") = "Removed from Depot" Then ReconciliationID = "1"
MsgBox ("Step 1")
          targetSheet.Range("A1").EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(ImportRecordCount).Insert shift:=xlDown ' Add the blank rows
MsgBox ("Step 2")
          targetSheet.Range("B2:AB" & ImportRecordCount + 1).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A3:AA" & ImportRecordCount + 2).Value ' Bring in the big pile of data
MsgBox ("Step 3")
          targetSheet.Range("AJ2:AJ" & ImportRecordCount + 1).Value = ReconciliationID ' To help with reconciling shipments
          targetSheet.Range("AK2:AK" & ImportRecordCount + 1).Value = ReconciliationID ' To help with deployment timing
          'targetSheet.Range("AI2:AI" & ImportRecordCount + 1).Value = "=COUNTIFS($D:$D, D2, $F:$F, F2)" ' This is the helper formula for identifying duplicates (deprecated, but I'm saving the code)
          For TransactionCounter = 2 To ImportRecordCount + 1 ' Create and add the new Transaction ID values
            targetSheet.Range("a" & TransactionCounter) = TransactionID + ImportRecordCount - TransactionCounter + 1
          Next
        ' Close customer workbook
          customerWorkbook.Close
        ' Format the sheet properly
          Application.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
          Application.Cells.Font.Size = "8"
          Application.Cells.Font.Bold = False
          Application.Range("1:1").Font.Size = "10"
          Application.Range("1:1").Font.Bold = True
        ' Query the User -- delete the file?
          If MsgBox("Delete the local client-generated data file?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "(this will NOT affect your email)", vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbYes Then
            Kill customerFilename
            ' MsgBox ("File: " & vbCrLf & customerFilename & vbCrLf & "has been deleted.")
          End If
      End If ' If ContinueUpload = True Then
    End If ' If customerFilename <> "False" Then

End Sub
```

**edit**

I edited your original question to highlight things I found as suspect. These are things I felt are worth pointing out to you. I shaved everything else out as to focus on these particular issue. Review them and do soem research to see if you can find yourself in a better situation.

```
    MsgBox ("Step 2")

        'Ive never moved large amounts of data using this method. Ive always just used arrays. I have moved smaller bits of data though.
        ' I suspect that this might take a moment if the data set is large. Again use arrays to grab the data and move it.
        ' Edward says “This step takes about 70% of my delay — even if bringing in only a single line of data.”

        targetSheet.Range("B2:AB" & ImportRecordCount + 1).Value = sourceSheet.Range("A3:AA" & ImportRecordCount + 2).Value ' Bring in the big pile of data

    MsgBox ("Step 3")

      ' this loop is probably your main culprit of your performance issue. 
      ' Edward says “Nope, this flies by. It is not the issue at all. I have verified this already.”
      ' Learn how to construct an array of data on the fly and then learn how to dump the entire array to 
      ' sheet using a simple method.

        For TransactionCounter = 2 To ImportRecordCount + 1 ' Create and add the new Transaction ID values
            targetSheet.Range("a" & TransactionCounter) = TransactionID + ImportRecordCount - TransactionCounter + 1
        Next
```

Comment: The issue is youre interacting with the application's objects. Sadly, when you do this, the bigger the file, the bigger the lag you will observe will be. Not touching the application's objects will remove the lag. This means all things like "select/active/copy/paste" and all that fun formatting you done. Anything you do to the "physical" excel objects has huge performance hits and its exponentially awful the bigger the worksheets/workbooks are. Do you need the formatting? And is excel the correct tool for this? Wouldnt a light weight ms-access serve better?

Comment: "Do you need the formatting?"

The font formatting happens after the lag.

"And is excel the correct tool for this?"

Excel is the tool I had and had the most experience working in. It is the tool that everyone else in the org is using.

"Wouldnt a light weight ms-access serve better?"

It is unlikely I would be able to convince everyone else in the org to switch to using Access to create reports on transactional data.

But if I knew it well enough to make the UI very slick, then I might take a few months to learn it enough.

Comment: Do you have a formulas in either the source or destination workbooks?  It may be worth disabling calculation at the beginning of the code and then enabling it again at the end.  This will prevent formulas from recalculating during the insert statement as well as during the data import.  If formula recalculations are what's causing the delay, this should mitigate it.

Comment: Similarly, if you have coded workbook or worksheet events, you can disable events to prevent those from running if that could be the cause of the slowdown.

Comment: "Do you have a formulas in either the source or destination workbooks?" I do. That's a good idea, but I had to discard it for that reason. :)

Comment: @EdwardMartiniii You say that most of your delay is after step 3 yet i see formatting occurring in step 3. So which is it? Formatting means stuff like font weight, size etc

Comment: If I had time to analyze and refactor this, I would be able to reduce the lag up to a certain point. The fact of the matter is youre issue is in fact due to interacting wth excel's "front end" or as I previous said "the applications physical objects" i.e worksheets, cells, ranges etc etc. You could learn to do all the processing in memory using arrays and do all the object stuff at the end. This however doesnt solve the fact that any object interactions that affect larger objects (like large ranges) will still take a while b/c thats just how excel works.

Comment: Doug, please check what I wrote. About 30% of my delay is between step 1 and 2. About 70% of my delay is between step 2 and step 3. Regardless of how much data I am bringing in — 1 line or 100 lines (I rarely import more than 150 lines at a time). Everything before step 1 is inconsequential. Everything after step 3 is inconsequential. I have confirmed this.

Comment: "Do you have a formulas in either the source or destination workbooks?" Hm, following up on this. My destination workbook has formulas in it, so when I insert the blank rows, I gotta let those expand too. But I want to check more deeply into this because 1. my SOURCE files might not have formulas (meaning I could switch off calc), BUT 2. the formulas in my destination file might refer to the new data (in which case I can't switch off the calc). You got my brain chewing on this one...

Comment: @tigeravatar: thank you for the suggestion. I tried disabling calculation directly AFTER I added the rows, and then re-enabling it just before the Step 3 message box. Sad to report that if it helped speed things up, it did not do so in a way that was measurably faster than before. But it was an interesting avenue to check!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a lot of good things going here. A few things that I saw that could potentially be changed to improve your performance.

First, between "Step 1" and "Step 2": In my  experience, adding rows takes longer than using rows that already exist. It looks like you are basically "pushing" everything down to make room for the new data, such that the newly entered data is at the top and the oldest data is at the bottom. (Correct me if I am wrong on any of this.) If you were to simply add the data to the end of the sheet, you would probably see some performance improvements, although I don't know how big of an improvement it would be.

Second, between "Step 2" and "Step 3": I have found that using `.Value2` as opposed to `.Value` can give you some performance improvements, and the larger the data the bigger the improvement. This has a down side - Value2 does not retain any of the formatting that might be present, meaning that the number type (date, accounting, etc) does not pull over correctly. If this is something that you do not need, then you can use Value2.

Finally, other methods: When I run extensive macros, I always try to do everything I can to get a performance boost. You can get slight boosts across the board by using tricks like turning off screen updating (`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`), just be sure to turn it back on at the end of the macro.

I hope that this helps you figure it out! If all else fails, you can do it once or twice by hand to remember how much faster it is using the macro! Haha. Good Luck!

Comment: "It looks like you are basically "pushing" everything down to make room for the new data, such that the newly entered data is at the top and the oldest data is at the bottom."

Correct.

This makes searching later much faster because searching starts at the top and goes down until either results are found or end-of-data.

But I want to think about that as an option. I am not strictly MARRIED to data order.

Comment: "I have found that using .Value2 as opposed to .Value can give you some performance improvements, and the larger the data the bigger the improvement. This has a down side - Value2 does not retain any of the formatting that might be present, meaning that the number type (date, accounting, etc) does not pull over correctly. If this is something that you do not need, then you can use Value2."

Hm... I don't mind bringing over data raw, and then AFTER the data is imported, applying formatting to entire columns.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I will test the screen updating piece and let you know. Looks like new data files coming in in a few minutes anyway. :)

Comment: Unfortunately the cheap tricks to get small performance boosts do not address the issue at hand.

Comment: @EdwardMartinIII Bringing the raw data over and then formatting only what is needed later seems like a step in the right direction. If you do find a way to speed up large data transfers/copy pastes I will be interested to read about it! Good luck!

Comment: Disabling screenupdating did not offer a substantial decrease in input processing time. Sorry. That smelled like a promising idea!

Comment: Garrett, this may help to understand why I put it newest-first order: I import data only once. But other techs and managers pull reports from the data repeatedly throughout the day. So it is better to have the order to benefit their searches than to benefit my input process. That’s why I sort newest-to-oldest. Only my time is churned. :)

Comment: "Second, between "Step 2" and "Step 3": I have found that using .Value2 as opposed to .Value can give you some performance improvements, and the larger the data the bigger the improvement." It might be useful to know that I see a delay regardless of how much data I'm importing. Commonly, each import is roughly ten lines. They can vary from one line to, say, 150 lines, but usually, they are small imports of about ten lines. The delay is the same regardless of how many lines I'm importing. That is a most confounding thing! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .value2? In some scenarios it might bring you better performance. Check some performance comparatives here: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/

It's difficult seeing where's the issue without having access to the original sheets. Maybe the issue is with the data itself instead of your VBA code and sometimes you might need to clean your source data of the heavy stuff and then add it again if needed.

You could also look into doing some parts with Python but I guess that's out of the question if you don't want to add additional software layers to your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this at the beginning and end of your script. Just be sure to set everything back to TRUE!!

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

...CODE HERE...

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Unfortunately the cheap tricks to get small performance boosts do not address the issue at hand.

Comment: I tried the switching ScreenUpdating on and off again around the block of computationally intensive lines, but if it improved processing time, it did not improve it enough to be noticeable, sorry.